# When I use execCommand "insertText" it disappears after [VIDEO INCLUDED] - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, webautomation

[Video Example.mp4](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1184679468682453042/1185995506690826370/exampk.mp4?ex=6591a363&is=657f2e63&hm=60970a4998a1cf9d88e67f1aa11750912915200db4eff1cd4a0782de211db83a&)

(bear with the horrible video quality, you can see it happening anyway)

**Code:**

```js
function write(element, text) {
    const _el = element;
    _el.focus();
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, text); // Note that despite execCommand being marked as obsolete in 2020, t'll work in the foreseeable future because a new editing API specification is not finished yet, and knowing how slow such things usually move it may take another 5-20 years. 
    _el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true})); // usually not needed
    const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
        key: 'Enter',
        code: 'Enter',
        which: 13,
        keyCode: 13,
    });
    _el.dispatchEvent(event);

    console.log("Wrote '", text, "' in =>", element);
}
```

This is supposed to write on the input and then press ENTER...

but the text disappears before ENTER is pressed.

Could be some custom DOM, I'm trying to do it on [apollo.io](https://app.apollo.io) if that helps.

Comment: It means the site is probably listening to other events that aren't triggered by this code. Use devtools to set a breakpoint on keydown event and debug the site's listeners.

Comment: Is there a workaround/alternative way around that if what you said is correct? It's a chrome extension and I can't alter the site.

Comment: You'll have to use devtools to debug the code and find a solution.